# How does one evaluate $1+2-3-4+5+6-7-8+\cdots+50$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, arithmetic-progressions

> How does one evaluate the sum $1+2-3-4+5+6-7-8+\cdots+50$?

I know how to find the sum of [arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression): without the negative signs, one simply has
$$
1+2+\cdots+50=\frac{1}{2}\cdot(1+50)\cdot 50=51\times 25=1275.
$$

But how does one calculate the one above?

Comment: Consider a general case. Block them into $4$ consecutive numbers if you call the first one $n$.

Comment: Using @Robertz 's idea: better $1+2-3=0$, $-4+5+6-7=0$, $-8+9+10-11=0$,... $...-47=0$, $-48+49+50-51=0$  then correct for the last sum $0+51=51$

Comment: I find it disheartening that this question has received so many downvotes, and has been closed and deleted, and noone has commented as to why......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's
$$(1+5+...+49)+(2+6+...+50)-(3+7+...+51)-(4+8+...+52)+51+52=$$
$$=\frac{(2+12\cdot4)13}{2}+\frac{(4+12\cdot4)13}{2}-\frac{(6+12\cdot4)13}{2}-\frac{(8+12\cdot4)13}{2}+103=$$
$$=(1+2-3-4)\cdot13+103=51.$$

Comment: Thanks. But I don't get the idea behind this formula you just did.

Comment: @dimwitt04 It's a formula for the sum of the arithmetic progression: $S_{n}=\frac{(2a_1+(n-1)d)n}{2}$.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but where does 13 and 12 come from? Is it the number of terms?

Comment: @dimwitt04 Yes of course! If $n$ is a number of terms we obtain: $49=1+(n-1)4$, which gives $n=13$. I used $a_n=a_1+(n-1)d$.

Comment: Can down-voter explain us why did you do it?

Answer (score 19):

Look at the following:
$$1+\overbrace{(2-3)}^{-1}+\overbrace{(-4+5)}^1+\cdots+50$$

So you have $1+\overbrace{-1+1\cdots}^{\frac{48}2=24\text{ times}}+50$ and because $24$ is even the middle part become $0$ and you left with $1+50=51$ and done

moreover, you can generalize it:$$\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{k-1}{2}\right\rfloor}\times k=\begin{cases}n+1 &\text{if}\,\,\,(-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor}=1,&n\equiv0\pmod{2}\\
1 &\text{if}\,\,\, (-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor}=1,&n\equiv1\pmod{2}\\
-n &\text{if}\,\,\, (-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor}=-1,&n\equiv0\pmod{2}\\
0 &\text{if}\,\,\, (-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor}=-1,&n\equiv1\pmod{2}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 10):

Note that your sum can be written as
$$\underbrace{[(1-3)+(2-4)]}_{-4}+\underbrace{[(5−7)+(6−8)]}_{-4}+\dots +\underbrace{[(45−47)+(46−48)]}_{-4}+49+50$$
that is $-4\cdot(48/4)+49+50=-48+49+50=51.$
More generally
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{k-1}{2}\right\rfloor}\cdot k =\begin{cases}
-n&\text{if $n\equiv 0\pmod{4}$}\\
1&\text{if $n\equiv 1\pmod{4}$}\\
n+1&\text{if $n\equiv 2\pmod{4}$}\\
0&\text{if $n\equiv 3\pmod{4}$}.\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: (+1) I was just about to post an answer similar to the first part of this. Good generalization!

Comment: @Holo Our generalizations are equivalent...

Answer (score 9):

Note that $1+2-3=0$. Moreover, you will have -4+5+6-7 and so on... if you consider pairs of numbers, you will always have +1. How much times do you do this computation?

Comment: And if it ended with - 51 the sum would be 0...